# What film form is Les Ordres by Michel Brault?

Tags: documentary

I know that genre is not the same as the film form. Is Les Ordres documentary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia [calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docufiction) this film's unique blend of fact and fiction **'docufiction'**.

> Docufiction (or docu-fiction, often confused with docudrama) is the cinematographic combination of documentary and fiction. It is a film genre which attempts to capture reality such as it is (as direct cinema or cinéma vérité) and which simultaneously introduces unreal elements or fictional situations in narrative in order to strengthen the representation of reality using some kind of artistic expression.

It [lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_docufiction_films) *Les Ordres* as one of the examples of this genre.